# Unable to extract roller weblogger src 5.0 RC2

Tags: apache

recently i downloaded the roller weblogger source from this loaction:
http://people.apache.org/~snoopdave/apache-roller-5.0/ 
When i tried to extract the source to some location, 
it says unable to extract zip file or the zip file may be damaged.

Please help me where can i download the extractable file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the files in that directory were refreshed on Dec 30, after you asked the question.

So if there was a corrupted file, it has been replaced. Please try again.

Another approach is to fetch the code from Subversion as described here:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ROLLER/Build+Guide